# Apps script Image doesnt visible on web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to set image to html form web-app in title like logo but it doesn't work.

What I do wrong? I found script in other theme here. Image is shared for everyone in my company how it recommended. Image is located in Google drive

```html
              <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=14GDoNMZxgHlfTKMHmtamXmu93y2jaDy6" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
```

Comment: It should be shared with anyone on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to use an `iframe` with the image preview link.*

#### Code Snippet:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/[ID]/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```